# C++ compare vector and list

Tags: c++, list, if-statement, vector, compiler-errors

I have this error:

> no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::__cxx11::list') C/C++ Problem

Because of this:

```
if (vetorTop[i] == *adj[u]){...
```

They are inicialised:

```
adj = new list <int>[N];
vector <int> vetorTop;
```

Any hints or help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up operator precedence and then realize that `[]` binds stronger than `*` and therefore you need `(*adj)[u]`.

Comment: If you are comparing two containers for equality, consider using [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux adj c'est une liste d'adjacence et du coup il me faudra faire une autre comparaison pour chaque entrée de la liste. J'ai l'impression que le problème vient vraiment des types, aide moi stp.

Comment: `new list <int>[N];` should be frowned upon... Why not `std::vector<std::list<int>>` or `std::array<std::list<int>, N>`, or worse `std::unique_ptr<std::list<int>[]>`? ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how list must be used. The following code is not doing what you think:

```
adj = new list <int>[N];
```

This allocate an array of `N` empty `std::list<int>`.

On the other hand, this following code create a linked list of `N` elements:

```
std::list<int> adj{N};
```

Then you can compare the two containers like this:

```
bool isEqual = std::equal(std::begin(vetorTop), std::end(vetorTop), std::begin(adj), std::end(adj));
```

Note that if the two containers would be `std::vector`, the comparison would be done like this:

```
bool isEqual = vetorTop == adj;
```